# Search multiple columns at once for a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I inherited some code that searches for a string across multiple columns in a table. My predecessor used dynamic SQL to do this, like so:

```
SET @tmpSQL9a = @tmpSQL9a +
'and ( ' + CHAR(13) +

'           charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(h.RegionName,'''')) > 0  ' + CHAR(13) +
'           or  charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(h.City,'''')) > 0  ' + CHAR(13) +
'           or  charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(h.[StAte],'''')) > 0  ' + CHAR(13) +
'           or  charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(h.Zip,'''')) > 0  ' + CHAR(13) +
'           or  charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(h.PhoneNumber,'''')) > 0  ' + CHAR(13) +
'           or  charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(ca.FirstName,'''')) > 0   ' + CHAR(13) +
'           or  charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(ca.LastName,'''')) > 0   ' + CHAR(13) +
'           or  charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(ca.PrimaryPHone,'''')) > 0   ' + CHAR(13) +
'           or  charindex(''' + @parDashboardFilter_Search + ''',coalesce(ca.SecondaryPhone,'''')) > 0   ' + CHAR(13) +
```

This is a small sample: in this one instance, there are about 40 more lines of criteria written just as you see above. I have to imagine that there's a better way, but googling hasn't helped and my brain is fried.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't see why this would need dynamic SQL at all, if I am honest; apart from to make a significant security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would as your predecessor did, however, without the SQL injection; which is a *massive* security vulnerability.

An alternative would be to use an `EXISTS` with a subquery that unpivots the columns, something like this:

```sql
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM(VALUES(h.RegionName),
                         (h.City), --Obviously list all your columns, not just these 3
                         (h.State)) V(SearchString)
              WHERE V.SearchString LIKE '%' + @parDashboardFilter_Search  + '%')
```

Comment: I've not seen that syntax before. I've tried to search it up but I've no idea what I'm really looking at and can't find a combination of terms that gets me anything useful. Where could I read more about it? I mean, EXISTS, yes, but not FROM(VALUES...V(...

Comment: @BillinKansasCity did you try the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: It's a combination of features, @BillinKansasCity . `EXISTS`, which is well documented, as is `LIKE`. The `VALUES` table construct is being used to unpivot the columns, turning them into rows so that a single scalar expression can be used.

Comment: @DaleK Didn't know what to search for: you will note that "Table Value Constructor" does not appear in my question or the explanation. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @BillinKansasCity I googled "SQL Server Values" - which is pretty much exactly what you asked.

Comment: This doesn't solve all the problems the OP requested - dynamic list of columns...

Comment: Apart from the columns aren't dynamic in the question, @SimchaKhabinsky . They use "dynamic" SQL, sure, but they're just injecting the parameter, which is just a security flaw; parameters should be *parametrised* (the hint is in the name). I mention this both in the answer and in the comment under the question.

Comment: They actually mention *nothing* about dynamic columns in the question.

Answer (score 2):

And for completeness, one more option via XML/XQuery.

It is checking if parameter's value belongs to a sequence of values for all columns in a row.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, City VARCHAR(20), State CHAR(2), Zip VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (City, State, Zip) VALUES
('Miami', 'FL', '33160'),
('Dallas', 'TX', '15098'),
('Los Angeles', 'CA', '45660');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @par_Search VARCHAR(20) = 'TX';

SELECT t.*, x
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE) AS t1(x)
WHERE x.exist('/r/*[text() = sql:variable("@par_Search")]') = 1;
```

**Output**

| ID | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Dallas | TX | 15098 |

Comment: @Charlieface, I followed your advice and removed not needed `ROOT('root')`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just another little option where you don't have to list all the columns..

```
Select A.*
  From YourTable A
  Where (Select A.* for JSON Path) like '%MySearchString%'
```

Note:  If you have (for example) a column named `PHONE` and you search `'PHONE'` you will get all rows where `PHONE` is not null